# Convert/Migrate spot instance VM to pay as you go VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I need to Convert/Migrate spot instance VM to pay as you go VM.  The instance is stopped and I cannot start it due to availability.

How can this be done? Preferably with a script.

Comment: here somebody wrote a script to do the opposite way. I would assume you should be able to use the same path https://gist.github.com/larryclaman/5a3bb2a7b0bb7b559b1af192469c718a

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I don't think you can convert a Spot VM to a regular VM. You would have to delete the VM and attach the disk to a new pay-as-you-go VM.

Since there is no SLA for Azure Spot VMs and they can be evicted at any time, it is recommended that you use standard VMs instead of Azure Spot Virtual Machines if you need capacity right away.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the PS script to convert PYUG to SPOT VMs. It will not work for VMs with extensions as we will be recreating from existing disks. After verifying succesful conversion delete the backup snapshots.

```
Function Convert-PYUG2SPOT {
    Param (
        # Set variables to your specifics
        $resourceGroup,
        $vmName,
        $subscriptionName,
        [switch]$force
    )
    $WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

    $context = Set-AzContext $subscriptionName
    Write-Output "Setting context to $($subscriptionName)"
    # Get the details of the VM to be moved to the Availability Set
    $originalVM = Get-AzVM `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
        -Name $vmName

    try {
        # Check whether already logged-in
        $setAzContext = (az account set --name $subscriptionName)
        $updateresource = (az resource update --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $vmName --resource-type virtualMachines
--namespace Microsoft.Compute --set properties.storageProfile.osDisk.deleteOption=detach)
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host 'You need to login'
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { exit 1 }
    }
    # checking for dependencies
    $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMName $vmName
    $extensionExist = ($vm.Extensions | Select-Object Publisher, VirtualMachineExtensionType, TypeHandlerVersion)
    if ($extensionExist) {
        $extensionExist
        Write-Host 'Make sure you note the installed extensions, that you can configure later on the converted VM.'
        Write-Host 'Please re-run the automation with the -force switch to initiate the conversion.'
    }
    if ($extensionExist -and $force) {
        Write-Host 'Initiating the conversion.'
        # Create the basic configuration for the replacement VM.
        $newVM = New-AzVMConfig `
            -VMName $originalVM.Name `
            -VMSize $originalVM.HardwareProfile.VmSize `
            -Priority 'Spot' -MaxPrice -1

        # Confgure OS Disk
        Set-AzVMOSDisk `
            -VM $newVM -CreateOption Attach `
            -ManagedDiskId $originalVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id `
            -Name $originalVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name

        if ($originalVM.OSProfile.WindowsConfiguration) {
            $newVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType = 'Windows'
        }
        else {
            $newVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType = 'Linux'
        }

        # Taking backup of OSdisks
        $osDiskid = $originalVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id
        $osDiskName = $originalVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name
        # Create Disk Snapshot
        $snapshot = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $osDiskid -Location $originalVM.Location -CreateOption copy
        $newsnap = New-AzSnapshot `
            -Snapshot $snapshot `
            -SnapshotName "$($osDiskName)_snapshot" `
            -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup

        $randomNumber = Get-Random -Maximum 100
        foreach ($disk in $originalVM.StorageProfile.DataDisks) {
            # Taking backup of disks
            # Get Current VM Data Disk metadata.
            $dataDiskid = $disk.ManagedDisk.Id
            $dataDiskName = ($disk.Name).ToLower()

            # Create Disk Snapshot
            $snapshot = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $dataDiskid -Location $originalVM.Location -CreateOption copy
            $newsnap = New-AzSnapshot `
                -Snapshot $snapshot `
                -SnapshotName "$($dataDiskName)_$($randomNumber)" `
                -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
        }

        # Add NIC(s) and keep the same NIC as primary
        foreach ($nic in $originalVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces) {
            if ($nic.Primary -eq 'True') {
                Add-AzVMNetworkInterface `
                    -VM $newVM `
                    -Id $nic.Id -Primary
            }
            else {
                Add-AzVMNetworkInterface `
                    -VM $newVM `
                    -Id $nic.Id
            }
        }

        if ($originalVM.AvailabilitySetReference.Id) {
            Write-Output "Warning: VM $originalVM.Name is in an availability set. Spot VMs cannot run in availability sets."
        }

        # Remove the original VM
        Remove-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vmName -Force

        New-AzVM `
            -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
            -Location $originalVM.Location `
            -VM $newVM `
            -DisableBginfoExtension

        foreach ($attachDisk in $originalVM.StorageProfile.DataDisks) {
            $dataDiskid = ($attachDisk.ManagedDisk.Id).ToLower()
            $dataDiskName = ($attachDisk.Name).ToLower()
            Write-Output "Attaching $($dataDiskName)"
            Write-Output $dataDiskid
            Write-Output $dataDiskName
            $vm = Get-AzVM -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
            $vm = Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $vm `
                -Name $dataDiskName `
                -ManagedDiskId $dataDiskid `
                -Lun $attachDisk.Lun `
                -CreateOption Attach
            Write-Output " --- Adding data disk $($dataDiskName) to $($vmName)"
            Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
        }
    } }
```